# How to get list of all header files included in C source file?

Tags: python, c, parsing

I have tried parsing files using `#include` by Python. I have tried to match pattern using `sed` command. Both these ways I get garbage data. For example, if in some comment I have `/* #include "header.h" */` I get those lines as well. How to avoid this?

Comment: can you post code what ever you tried?

Comment: do you have any code that u have tried out so far !!

Comment: I tried : sed -nr \'/#include/p\' file.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using something like [pycparser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycparser) that parses C files? It may be overkill for your question, but it does allow much more advanced parsing options.

Comment: The re module serches for all the matches of #includes. The problem is when a comment is multi line I am not able to filter the multi line comments if I get garbage value for ex. /*--------------

Comment: Can you tell me how do i use pycparser?

Answer (score 7):

GCC supports the `-H` option.  Consider the source file `hw.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) { puts("Hello world"); return 0; }
```

On Mac OS X 10.9.4 with GCC 4.8.1:

```
$ gcc -H -c hw.c
. /usr/include/stdio.h
.. /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h
... /usr/include/sys/_symbol_aliasing.h
... /usr/include/sys/_posix_availability.h
.. /usr/include/Availability.h
... /usr/include/AvailabilityInternal.h
.. /usr/include/_types.h
... /usr/include/sys/_types.h
.... /usr/include/machine/_types.h
..... /usr/include/i386/_types.h
.. /usr/include/sys/_types/_va_list.h
.. /usr/include/sys/_types/_size_t.h
.. /usr/include/sys/_types/_null.h
.. /usr/include/sys/_types/_off_t.h
.. /usr/include/sys/_types/_ssize_t.h
.. /usr/include/secure/_stdio.h
... /usr/include/secure/_common.h
Multiple include guards may be useful for:
/usr/include/secure/_stdio.h
/usr/include/sys/_posix_availability.h
/usr/include/sys/_symbol_aliasing.h
$
```

Comment: +1 That's the easy way. something new to know.

Answer (score 3):

Once you start thinking about non-trivial cases like

```c
/* #include <header.h> */
```

you'll soon reach the point where it is no longer really practical to write your own dependency extractor.

Consider for example these:

```c
#define PLUGIN "my_extension.h"
#include PLUGIN

#ifdef WITH_CURSES
#  include <curses.h>
#endif
```

You can continue the list indefinitely.  If you want to handle all these correctly, you'll end up implementing a full preprocessor.

I don't know what you want to do with the generated list of flies but a common situation is to determine on which files a compilation unit depends, for example to generate makefiles.  Most compilers have included special support for this.  In GCC, it is the `-M` option.

**main.c**

```c
#include <alpha.h>

/* #include <beta.h> */

#ifdef PLUGIN
#include PLUGIN
#endif

#if WITH_DELTA
#include <delta.h>
#endif
```

**alpha.h**

```c
#include <epsilon.h>
```

Let **beta.h**, **gamma.h**, **delta.h** and **epsilon.h** be empty (or, at least, not `#include` anything).

```
$ gcc -I. -M main.c
main.o: main.c /usr/include/stdc-predef.h alpha.h epsilon.h

$ gcc -I. -DPLUGIN='<gamma.h>' -M main.c
main.o: main.c /usr/include/stdc-predef.h alpha.h epsilon.h gamma.h

$ gcc -I. -DWITH_DELTA=1 -M main.c
main.o: main.c /usr/include/stdc-predef.h alpha.h epsilon.h delta.h
```

Even if you are not ultimately trying to generate a makefile, parsing the preprocessor's output will be *a lot* easier than walking your own way through the source files.

Comment: I tried using -M option of GCC. if the headers are not in same directory as the one with source file the i get error: No such file or directory

Comment: You must add the respective directories to the include path via the `-I` option, just as if you were actually compiling.

Comment: makedepend worked for me for getting the header files

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler supports the `-E` (or similar) option, something like this may be useful:

```
cc -E myprogram.c | grep '^# 1 '
```

The `-E` option says just run the preprocessing stage and show the results.

An advantage of this method is that you can include any important `-I` and `-D` command line options as you would for a normal compile, thus capturing any behavior change those might engender.

Comment: This will work on gcc and clang, but you could use `-MD` or `-H` to better effect.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the grep utility (Linux, MacOS X):

```
grep '/^\s*#/' my_file.c
```

or (for a multi-file search)

```
grep '/^\s*#/' *.c
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work at all...

Comment: Grep doesn't understand `\s` (unless you're using gnu grep, and even then you need to specify `-P` to enable Perl-style regexen). Use `[[:space:]]` instead. But anyway, this could still fail if the supposed `#include` is inside of a `/*` comment.

Answer (score -1):

I use re module with Match and Search functions. Search will find the text anywere in the string while match starts from the beginning of the string

Comment: The re module serches for all the matches of #includes. The problem is when a comment is multi line I am not able to filter the multi line comments if I get garbage value for ex. /*-------------- #include stuff ---------*/

Comment: you are right, I was thinking of matching per line. without parsing the entire file how do you think to do it?

Comment: Ill need to use some tool of compiler or any open source parser